# How do I preserve text to output all at once in a file in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I would like to know if there is a function like to preserve the text formating (like spaces, line breaks) cause I am creating a `.bat` file the create another `.bat` file accordingly.

Now if I want to output text to create the 2nd `.bat` file I would echo 1 line at a time.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET file=output.bat
ECHO @ECHO OFF > %file%
ECHO ECHO HELLO >> %file%
ECHO PAUSE >> %file%
Pause
```

The method above is really inefficient so I would like to output it all at once.

So can I output the text like this?

```
ECHO "@ECHO OFF
ECHO HELLO
PAUSE">%file%
```

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if i get what you need, but if you add a ^ to the end of the line you can keep typing

Comment: So `^` at the end of the line shall be the same as enter?

Comment: yes if you are used to bash script ti would be similar to \

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code is inefficient, but not necessarily for the reason you've implied. I would not particularly say that concatenating multiple lines as opposed to typing `ECHO` at the beginning of each is inefficient, it would just require a little less typing, on the one occasion you create the initial script. The inefficiency is because you are opening a file for writing, writing to it, and then closing it, on each of your `ECHO` lines. You also appear to be adding an unnecessary space character to the end of each of your destination file lines too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect a block of code at once

```
@ECHO OFF
SET file=output.bat
(
  ECHO @ECHO OFF
  ECHO ECHO HELLO
  ECHO PAUSE 
) > %file%
```

Another way is to use the multi line character `^`, but then you need also an empty line after each text line

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "file=output.bat"
(
  ECHO @ECHO OFF^

  ECHO HELLO^

  PAUSE
) > "%file%"
```

Comment: Best practice to use quoting for setting the `file` variable and when it is used. `SET "file=output.txt"` and `) >"%file%"`

Comment: @jeb But I still have to echo it on every line right?

Comment: @Dumdum Normally yes, but you could also use an alternative solution with the multiline character

Answer (score 1):

An altenative to Jebs solution is to use a prefix string and a `for /f` loop with `findstr` to read the text to be output to your secondary file.

```bat
@ECHO OFF & CD /d "%~dp0"
(
 For /f "tokens=1,* Delims=#" %%G in ('%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /bl ":-#" "%~f0"')Do Echo(%%H
)>"outfile.bat"
outfile.bat

:-#@ECHO OFF
:-#ECHO HELLO
:-#PAUSE
```

**Notes:**

- The Delim character cannot be present in text to be output. `#` is used as it's meaningless in batch syntax
- The prefix string is always begun with `:` as this denotes a label and is disregarded by the interpreter when the batch runs.
- an intermediary prefix character ( `-` in the above example ) allows multiple files to be stored in the source file. Simply change the prefix string in the `findstr` search term accordingly.
- `/bl ":-#" "%~f0"` findstr searches the running batch `"%~f0"` for the `l`iteral string `:-#` at the `b`eginning of each line.
- variables will not be expanded

Comment: with `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=# %%G in (...) do echo %%H`, the delimiter char *can*  be present in text - just not as first char.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET file=output.bat
ECHO @ECHO OFF > %file%
ECHO ECHO HELLO >> %file%
ECHO PAUSE >> %file%
Pause
```

Can be replaced **with limitations** as

```
@ECHO @ECHO OFF ^& ECHO HELLO ^& PAUSE >output.bat
```